# How to fill missing value based on column comparison Python

Tags: python, regex, string, multiple-columns

I want to fill the missing values in col 2 to corresponding col1.

```
import pandas as pd
data={"col1":["A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","A"], "col2":["{hey1}"," ","{hello2}","{hey2}","{he1}","{hello3}","set()","set()","{hey1}"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

It should fill it with some rules, given below:
 for example, if A is occuring four times and out of 4, it has corresponding col2 value for three times and fourth one is missing,
    so missing value should be a combination of all three. Like in this case 3 values are hey1, hey2, hey1. Fourth missing
    should contain hey2, hey1.
Set() is the garbage value, I dont want that value. So, I want to remove it, before dealing with column comparison.
Desired output:

```
col1 col2
A     hey1
B    he1
C    hello2
A    hey2
B    he1
C     hello3
A    hey1,hey2
B    he1
A    hey1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {"col1": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A"],
        "col2": ["", " ", "hello2", "hey2", "he1", "hello3", " ", "", ""]}
col1 = data["col1"]
col2 = data["col2"]

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
new_col2 = []
for i, tup in enumerate(list(zip(col1, col2))):
    key, value = tup
    if not value.strip():
        new_val = ", ".join(d[key])
        if not new_val:
            if len(new_col2) >= 1:
                new_val = new_col2[i - 1]
            else:
                new_val = ""

        new_col2.append(new_val)
    else:
        d[key].append(value)
        new_col2.append(value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am getting error ` list index out of range on line new_val = new_col2[i - 1]`, when I am applying the same code on the real time example

Comment: Updated. Now if first element is empty string, will leave it empty

Comment: I have edited question with minor change, I am getting set() value and it is a garbage value. I want to remove it. When the above solution finds set(), it throws error `set() object has no attribute strip`. Could you please help in this?